# Smallest ellipse by area to enclose 2D points

Tags: optimization, conic-sections, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am interested in writing an algorithm that, for a given set of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, finds the equation of the smallest ellipse by area to enclose all $n$ points. Here's where I'm at:

The general equation of an ellipse is $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey-1=0$. This ellipse has area $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{4AC-B^2}}$ and by definition satisfies $4AC-B^2>0$. Therefore to minimize the area of this conic, we can minimize the scalar value function $\phi(x)=B^2-4AC$.

I'm going to simplify this question to emphasize the part I don't understand. Imagine now that we have only 3 points that need to be enclosed in the ellipse, (1,1), (1,5), and (7,3). Because there are only 3 points, we can assume the smallest ellipse would pass through all 3, and we now have a quadratic optimization problem under equality constraints as follows:

$$\min_{x}\phi(x)=B^2-4AC$$

s.t.

$$c_{1}(x) = A+B+C+D+E-1=0$$
$$c_{2}(x)=A+5B+25C+D+5E-1=0$$
$$c_{3}(x)=49A+21B+9C+7D+3E-1=0$$

where $x = $ $[A$ $B$ $C$ $D$ $E]^{T}$

Using Lagrange multipliers, we have Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) = \phi(x)-\lambda_{1}c_{1}(x)-\lambda_{2}c_{2}(x)-\lambda_{3}c_{3}(x)$$

We now set $\nabla_{x}\mathcal{L} = 0$ and $\nabla_{\lambda}\mathcal{L} = 0$. These conditions (KKT) produce an 8 x 8 linear system. Tediously, here it is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 &4 &0 &0 &1 &1 &49 \\
0 &-2 &0 & 0 &0 &1 &5 &21\\
4 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1 &25 &9\\
0 &0 &0&0&0&1&1&7\\
0 &0&0&0&0&1&5&3\\
1&1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\
1&5&25&1&5&0&0&0\\
49&21&9&7&3&0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A\\
B\\
C\\
D\\
E\\
\lambda_{1}\\
\lambda_{2}\\
\lambda_{3}\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\1\\1\\1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

This is the equivalent of the saddle point matrix, and is nonsingular. I think this makes sense because reasonably there should only be one smallest ellipse that encloses the 3 given points.

The issue is that the solution to this linear system produces a Langrange multiplier that is negative, and the entire solution when plotted is obviously wrong. So here are my questions:

1. Am I setting this problem up correctly?
2. If so, what is an intuitive explanation as to why this method is not producing a feasible solution.
3. What method would you recommend, considering that this is a simplified version of the problem? The ultimate goal will be to find the ellipse that will enclose $n$ points, which will produce a quadratic optimization problem under inequality constraints.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: $\dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt{4AC-B^2}}$ is the area for **central** ellipse $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2=1$ only.  Minimizing ellipse implies maximizing $4AC-B^2$.  Note that for a triangle inscribed in a **given** ellipse, the maximal triangle with the eccentric angles for the vertices differ by $120^{\circ}$.

Comment: @NgChungTak, I believe this formula holds for a translated ellipse as well since by definition a translation preserves all properties of a shape and is only a transformation on its location.

That is an interesting note about the inscribed triangle. Do you see a way that could be applied in this problem?

Comment: Translation normally doesn’t affect the quadratic part of the general conic equation, but it does affect the constant term. In the equation you’re using, this term is normalized to $-1$. Doing so involves scaling the quadratic part of the equation, so a translation also effectively changes the scale.

Comment: See also https://www.cs.cornell.edu/cv/OtherPdf/Ellipse.pdf

Answer (score 3):

- Area of a triangle with vertices at eccentric angles $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ is

  $$\Delta=2ab
   \left |
     \sin \frac{\alpha-\beta}{2} \sin \frac{\beta-\gamma}{2} \sin \frac{\gamma-\alpha}{2}
   \right |$$
- The triangle's area is maximal when $\alpha-\beta=\beta-\gamma=\pm 120^{\circ}$, that is

  $$\Delta=\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{4}ab$$
- Note that

  $$\sin x+\sin (x+120^{\circ})+\sin (x+240^{\circ})=0$$

  $$\cos x+\cos (x+120^{\circ})+\cos (x+240^{\circ})=0$$

  the centroid $G$ for maximal triangle is an invariant that is the centre of the ellipse.
- Let $\boldsymbol{u}=\vec{GA}$, $\boldsymbol{v}=\vec{GB}$, $\boldsymbol{w}=\vec{GC}$, the column vectors for the semi-axes be $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$ and $\boldsymbol{\mu}$.

  Now

  \begin{align}
     \boldsymbol{0} &= \boldsymbol{u}+\boldsymbol{v}+\boldsymbol{w} \\[5pt]
     \boldsymbol{u} &=
     \boldsymbol{\lambda} \cos (\theta-60^{\circ})+
     \boldsymbol{\mu} \sin (\theta-60^{\circ}) \\[5pt]
     \boldsymbol{v} &=
     \boldsymbol{\lambda} \cos (\theta+60^{\circ})+
     \boldsymbol{\mu} \sin (\theta+60^{\circ}) \\[5pt]
     \boldsymbol{\lambda} &=
     \frac{2[\boldsymbol{u}\sin (\theta+60^{\circ})-
             \boldsymbol{v}\sin (\theta-60^{\circ})]}{\sqrt{3}} \\[5pt]
     \boldsymbol{\mu} &=
     \frac{2[\boldsymbol{v}\cos (\theta-60^{\circ})-
             \boldsymbol{u}\cos (\theta+60^{\circ})]}{\sqrt{3}} \\[5pt]
     0 &= \boldsymbol{\lambda} \cdot \boldsymbol{\mu} \\[5pt]
     0 &= \boldsymbol{u} \cdot \boldsymbol{v} \sin 2\theta-
          \frac{u^2}{2} \sin (2\theta+120^{\circ})-
          \frac{v^2}{2} \sin (2\theta-120^{\circ}) \\[5pt]
     \tan 2\theta &=
     \frac{u^2-v^2}{u^2+4\boldsymbol{u} \cdot \boldsymbol{v}+v^2} \sqrt{3}
   \end{align}
- Also note that

  \begin{align}
     \boldsymbol{u} \times \boldsymbol{v} &=
     \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \boldsymbol{\lambda} \times \boldsymbol{\mu} \\[5pt]
     |\boldsymbol{u} \times \boldsymbol{v}| &= \dfrac{2\Delta}{3} \\[5pt]
     A_{\text{min}} &= \pi \lambda \mu \\[5pt]
     &= \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}} |\boldsymbol{u} \times \boldsymbol{v}| \\[5pt]
     &= \dfrac{4\pi \Delta}{3\sqrt{3}} \\[5pt]
   \end{align}
- The (column) vector equation for the central conics is given by

  $$\boldsymbol{x}^T \mathbb{M} \, \boldsymbol{x}=1$$

  $$\mathbb{M}^{-1}=
   \begin{pmatrix} \boldsymbol{\lambda} & \boldsymbol{\mu} \end{pmatrix}
   \begin{pmatrix} \boldsymbol{\lambda}^T \\ \boldsymbol{\mu}^T \end{pmatrix}$$

> **Updates**
>
> The smallest ellipse is also known as [**Steiner circumellipse**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerCircumellipse.html).
>
> The [**Steiner inellipse**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerInellipse.html) has the maximum area of any inellipse.
>
> The Steiner inellipse is half of the Steiner circumellipse about the centroid of the triangle.
>
> If $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma \in \mathbb{C}$ are the vertices of the triangle and let
>
> $$f(z)=(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)(z-\gamma)$$
>
> then by [**Marden's_theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marden%27s_theorem) the foci of the Steiner inellipse is given by
>
> $$
>   f'(c)=0 \implies
>   c=\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}{3} \pm
>   \frac{\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2-
>               \beta \gamma-\gamma \alpha-\alpha \beta}}{3}$$
>
> Doubling the focal length immediately gives the foci for the Steiner circumellipse which are
>
> $$\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}{3} \pm
>     \frac{2\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2-
>                  \beta \gamma-\gamma \alpha-\alpha \beta}}{3}$$
>
> See also an article [**here**](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fd3b/7d1fadd19f0677f6f6faa4426115d4b57ef7.pdf) for your further interest.

Comment: Under your forth bullet you start using theta. Could you clarify what theta is?

Comment: Could you also clarify what the vector x is (used under your last bullet point), and what the scalar values u, v, mu, and lambda are? Are these scalars meant to be the magnitude of their respective vectors?

Comment: $\theta-60^{\circ}$, $\theta+60^{\circ}$ and $\theta+180^{\circ}$ are eccentric angles where $$\theta=\frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1} \frac{(u^2-v^2)\sqrt{3}}{u^2-\boldsymbol{u} \cdot \boldsymbol{v}+v^2}$$

Comment: All the ***bold italic*** are colume vectors $$\boldsymbol{x}=\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\boldsymbol{u}=\vec{GA}=\begin{pmatrix} x_1-\dfrac{x_1+x_2+x_3}{3} \\ y_1-\dfrac{y_1+y_2+y_3}{3} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$ and so on

Answer (score 2):

See these papers and the references therein:

- B. Gärtner, S. Schönherr,
  [Smallest Enclosing Ellipses - Fast and Exact](https://people.inf.ethz.ch/gaertner/subdir/texts/own_work/smell2exact_tr-b-97-03.pdf)
- B. Gärtner, S. Schönherr,
  [Smallest Enclosing Ellipses - An Exact and Generic Implementation](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/inst/pubs/tr-b-98-05.abstract.html)